# How to show Wordpress blog posts in Drupal's Search Api?

Tags: 7, views, search

We have a blog site on Wordpress that we want displayed in our search without having to create Drupal nodes for each blog post. We using the following below and were interested in seeing how we can do this as the [Wordpress Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/wordpress_migrate) and [Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) has not provided a way to do this.

All we want to do is display the blog post on our search (which using Apache Solr Search Index) in such a way that we pull the blog post title, description and a direct link to the post.

Comment: Have you tried using Aggregator module?

Comment: @sarathkm the issue is that the aggregator module will create a block that can be placed in some region to display that latest N number of items. We want to have our search api pull in the blog posts without creating nodes (if possible)?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can achive this :

1. [simple] Import the posts from wordpress rss with Feeds https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds
2. [more difficult] Crawl the Wordpress content and populate the Apache Solr index directly. You can use an open source crawler like [Apache Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/)
   The difficult part is that the external content is not managed by Drupal, only through Solr so you don't have many options to play with the indexed content in the Drupal site.